# Why WinWait() return after closing the window?

Tags: autoit

```
$win1 = WinWait("ToBeClosed")
WinClose($win1)
WinWait("ToBeClosed")
MsgBox(0, "", "Here!")
```

Why this message box be shown while the window is closed. Is it true to stop execution at the second call of WinWait() as long as the window hasn't been shown again?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing WinWaitClose

```
Opt("WinSearchChildren", 1) ;0=no, 1=search children also
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 2) ;1=start, 2=subStr, 3=exact, 4=advanced, -1 to -4=Nocase

$WinTitle = "ToBeClosed"
WinWait($WinTitle)
WinClose($WinTitle)
WinWaitClose($WinTitle)
WinWait($WinTitle)
MsgBox(0, "", "Here!")
```

Comment: I have tried this code in the reminders window of Outlook 2010, but it stops execution at WinWaitClose and doesn't proceed. Is there special case for that?

Comment: That means you didnt kill that window.
Try running WinCLose multiply times.